# ReactJs : convert string to float

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert string to Integer

```
price: get(product, 'price_range.minimum_price.final_price.value', '').float()
```

is **string**.

I have tried

```
price: parseFloat(get(product, 'price_range.minimum_price.final_price.value', ''))
```

but for price `15.00` it converts to `15`

Comment: What is `get` here? If the first line is actually a string, then the second line should work. But the error indicates that the `.float()` method doesn't exist, which has nothing to do with the `parseFloat()` call. Please add some more details about this so we can help you.

Comment: I have updated question

Comment: parseFloat works but it 15.00 it converts to 15

it does not converts to data type float

Comment: @devhs JS only has one Number type, which is generally a float (double) by default. `15` is the correct output

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`parseFloat('15.22')` will return `15.22` because it parses a floating point number. This means a number with a decimal point.

I think think you want `parseInt('15.22', 10)` which will return `15` because it parses an integer in base `10` (the second argument).

So try `parseInt()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you `parseFloat(string)`, it becomes a number or NaN - if you have extended the string object with a `.float()` method, it likely will not work on a number.

Try unary plus

```
price: +get(product, 'price_range.minimum_price.final_price.value', '');
```

to cast to whatever number it can cast to - if you want an integer like you say in your title, use `parseInt()`; to keep the decimals, use `parsFloat()`